# Dashboard in home page is not showing filtered

Tags: dashboard

I followed the steps to add a filter to a dashboard that I created. So far so good, but when I try to load the dashboard from the home page, it is not showing the filter. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Did you follow the standard steps ? Could you share link to any documentation from where you followed those steps?

Comment: I followed steps from following link: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dashboard_filters_editing.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, if you are using the filters set while viewing the dashboard in the `Dashboard` tab, then the dashboards displayed on the homepage will not be filtered.

There is also a [post on IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000gzChAAI) requesting this filter capability.